# What does DB: waitresource means in sys.sysprocesses?

Tags: sql-server

I'm monitoring SQL server's health by querying `sys.sysprocesses` View. There is `waitresource` column and there is a lot information about `PAG:,TAB:,KEY:,RID:` resources, but I can not find any information about DB: resource like `DB: 17:67. 17`  is `database_id`, but what means second number, 67?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably either `DatabaseID:ObjectID:IndexID` if the resource in question is a table or `DatabaseID:FileID:PageID` if a page is the resource.    See the documentation below for specifics on this.  I'd also recommend using the current DMVs and a list mapping older system objects to the corresponding current ones can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

[MSDN SQL Server Blocking](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/224453/inf-understanding-and-resolving-sql-server-blocking-problems)

Comment: I have seen this article, but unfortunately there are no information about DB resources. Do you think that 67 from "DB: 17:67" means object_id?

Comment: Have you tried using additional tracking, i.e. Extended Events or Profiler, to get more details on the wait you're seeing?

Comment: No. I was hoping to find a modern article describing all types of resources.